# Incorrect number of arguments for type RetryCallback

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring's retry library to retry a webservice call in case any error occurs if the service is down, or there is a network timeout. However, I keep getting the below error in my code - `Incorrect number of arguments for type RetryCallback<T,E>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Object>`. The method I am implementing the logic against returns void, so I basically can't have the retry call return anything. Please advise what mistake I have made here -

```
 RetryTemplate retryTemplate = createRetryTemplate(3, 1000);
    return retryTemplate.execute(new RetryCallback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object doWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws Exception {
            userUpdateService.updateUser(userName, userID);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RetryCallback](http://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/RetryCallback.html) asks for two type parameter, a return type and an exception type.

```
RetryTemplate retryTemplate = createRetryTemplate(3, 1000);
    return retryTemplate.execute(new RetryCallback<Object,Exception>() {
       @Override
       public Object doWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws Exception {
           userUpdateService.updateUser(userName, userID);
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/RetryCallback.html#doWithRetry%28org.springframework.retry.RetryContext%29) for `RetryCallback` specifies 2 types, where you've only specified one.

The second type is what derivative of `Throwable` you will (possibly) throw, eg `Exception`, which you also need to specify:

```
RetryTemplate retryTemplate = createRetryTemplate(3, 1000);
return retryTemplate.execute(new RetryCallback<Object, Exception>() {
    @Override
    public Object doWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws Exception {
        userUpdateService.updateUser(userName, userID);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The type [`RetryCallback`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/class-use/RetryCallback.html) accepts two generic parameters (a return type and a thrown exception type), but you are passing only one.

```
public interface RetryCallback<T, E extends Throwable> {
    T  doWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws E;
}
```

So you would want to instantiate it like this:

```
new RetryCallback<Object, Throwable>() { //...
```